# dynamodb efficient read capacity

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

For dynamodb databases with only a couple of requests per hour, what is the most efficient provisioning.
What is more expensive "On-Demand" capacity or a fixed capacity ?

By default AWS will propose a capacity of 5 reads, 5 writes for a table. See image below.

[image: an example]

Right now, I find it hard to estimate the costs or to compare the costs of different tables. Is there a way to get an overview of the costs per table, or perhaps some kind of trick just to make an estimate ?

## Edit:

I wanted to add some charts to show and quantify how little this database is actually used.

For my users table:
[image: users table]

For the vouchers table:
[image: vouchers table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/
For US East (Ohio)
1.25 /million writes
0.25 /million reads

https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/
For US East (Ohio)
$0.00065 per WCU per hour
$0.00013 per RCU per hour

So assuming a minimally provisioned table (1 RCU & 1 WCU) 24 hrs a day, 30 days a month..
$0.57 /per month...

That 57 cents would get you about 2 million on demands reads in a month...or 500K writes.

You don't mention the ratio of reads/writes.

One last thing to consider, AWS Free tier for DDB allows for 25GB of storage, 25 RCU and 25 WCU per month.  So assuming all your DDB fits there...it's free.

Comment: I have added some pictures giving you some more details about the actual usage of these tables.

Comment: @bvdb I'd create both as provisioned 1 maybe 2 RCU/WCU ... assuming those are your only tables, you'll fit easily in the free tier.

Comment: I've been an aws member for several years, so I fear that I am no longer free tier eligible at all. - But I figure that all differences are rather minimal ?

Comment: @bvdb AWS includes both a "free to new members" and an "always free"...the free DDB I mention is part of [always free](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%23always-free&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all).